# Can you play local multiplayer in Minecraft without an Xbox live gold subscription?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

Is lan play possible for Minecraft on the xbox without both accounts having gold?

E.g 2 xbox's, 2 silver accounts, 1 hosting, 1 connecting to host

Comment: Are you asking for xbox 360 or xbox one?

Answer (score 1):

You can not play Minecraft via System Link. You would have to connect to Xbox Live to play together. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed.

All local LAN Xbox's need Xbox gold to play together.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can because it's going through you router box, you don't really need Xbox live that's only for playing public on online servers not private servers.